# Easiest way to test if two collections have the same contents?

Tags: java, testing

Very often when writing tests I've to check if two collections have the same contents and sometimes even if they have the same order. So I endlessly end up doing the same thing:

```
assertEquals(collection1.size(), collection2.size());

for (ItemType item : collection1){
 if (!collection2.contains(item)) fail(); //This depends on the collection
}

//some more code is required to test ordering
```

Do you know of a good way to end this torment using some standard library?

Comment: How about using `collection1.equals(collection2)`?

Comment: The issue here is: do you always care about ordering?

Comment: I was referring to both situation, with and without ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use `equals()` method, because if you use `containsAll` then for two lists that have same elements can be equal **although there elements are in different order**. So using `containsAll` is not good way to compare `List`
Here is a demo

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

    public class TwoButtons {


        public static void main(String[] args){
            Collection<Integer> c1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
            Collection<Integer> c2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3,2,1));

            System.out.println("equals " + c1.equals(c2));
            System.out.println("containsAll " + c1.containsAll(c2));
        }
    }
```

output

```
equals false
containsAll true
```

Comment: Collections API doesn't guarantee the order of returning elements or duplicates. Eg a collection could be a set which would not have duplicates. Collection could be a list which would have a particular order of returning elements.

Comment: But List does http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object) this is what I was looking for and I didn't know that List has this property.

Comment: @gotch4 If you know you have `List`s, why are you using `Collection`s?

Comment: Yes so does my comment. When you use something like Collection<P> generic = new ArrayList<P>(); Then you are forced to use the iterator for the collection. Which would not guarantee the ordering. For that you would have to explicitly use a list. List<P> generic = new ArrayList<P>();

Comment: @Aeshang That is wrong. The declared type of a variable makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do use this as a condition

```
collection1.size()==collection2.size() && collection1.containsAll(collection2)
```

Here you are checking that both the collections are of same size as well as the have all the elements.

As per the comments by [joachim-isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson)
you can do this but will not be efficient.

```
collection1.containsAll(collection2) && collection2.containsAll(collection1)
```

You should use

[ReflextionAsserter](http://www.unitils.org/apidocs/org/unitils/reflectionassert/ReflectionAssert.html)

Comment: Well, it depends, I'm guessing `1,1,2` would compare equal to `1,2,2`?

Comment: +1. Alternatively, there is the option `collection1.containsAll(collection2) && collection2.containsAll(collection1)` which has extra points for simmetry but is probably slower).

Comment: Very good idea. Put this code in a Util class, hide the idea under a 'isEqual' or something and use it widely on the project. +1

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Collections API doesn't guarantee the order of returning elements or duplicates. Eg a collection could be a set which would not have duplicates but will edit my ans to add another condition.

Comment: Joachim is right. As per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object) contains uses indeed the equals method, so the the solution is not good when equals is implemented on value basis. I was looking for something like sol4me 's idea

Comment: IMO, this answer works only if the elements in the collection are unique.

Comment: Why is it down votes ? The question doesn't say equal it says contains.

Comment: Maybe because OP asked "...if two collections have the same contents and sometimes even _if they have the same order_."

Comment: Gotcha ... i missed that completely... Thanks for the info.